# Editing JSON files with tkinter textbox

Tags: json, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm entirely new to python so this might be the wrong way to go about this, but I have a list of lists I'm storing as a JSON (a list of sets of names)

EX:

```
[
  ["Autofu", "Avieanna ", "Deefi ", "Lasciell ", "Yogus"],
  ["Inalla", "Scorp", "Headsheals", "Aesir", "Kyvan"],
  ["Joejonas", "Wazzam","Perucho", "Discreet", "Explosive"]
]
```

And I want to display them in a tkinter textbox to allow users to easily edit the lists.
When I display them on the text box like this:

```
with open("player_roster.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as fin:
    roster = json.load(fin)

roster_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(roster_frame, undo=True, height=20, width=80)
roster_text.pack(expand=False, fill=BOTH)

for r in range(len(roster)):
    team = roster[r]
    roster_text.insert(INSERT, f"{team}\n")
```

It reformats to look like this:

```
['Autofu', 'Avieanna ', 'Deefi ', 'Lasciell ', 'Yogus']
['Inalla', 'Scorp', 'Headsheals', 'Aesir', 'Kyvan']
['Joejonas', 'Wazzam', 'Perucho', 'Discreet', 'Explosive']
```

I'm then calling a function to save any changes made to the lists, while trying to fix some of the formatting changes (it creates a new json for testing purposes)

```
def edit():
    roster_get = roster_text.get(1.0, 'end-1c').replace('\n', ', ')
    with open("player_roster_test.json", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fout:
        json.dump(roster_get, fout)
```

The new json file looks to be a string though

```
"['Autofu', 'Avieanna ', 'Deefi ', 'Lasciell ', 'Yogus'], ['Inalla', 'Scorp', 'Headsheals', 'Aesir', 'Kyvan'], ['Joejonas', 'Wazzam', 'Perucho', 'Discreet', 'Explosive']"
```

How can I get the Json and textbox to correctly share the lists?

Side question:
Some of the names in the list have special characters. They display on the textbox correctly, but when the edit function tries to grab the names, it turns the special characters into garbage? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the full `team` list, so that's why you are seeing all the []. Here's what i would do:

```py
for team in roaster:
    for player in team
        if player != team[-1]: # Doing if/else, to have nice ponctuation signs.
            roster_text.insert(INSERT, f"{player}, ")
        else:
            roster_text.insert(INSERT, f"{player}.")
    roster_text.insert(INSERT, "\n")
```

This way, you will have the names without brackets: `Alice, John, Mike, ..., Eric.` And the last player will end with a "." instead of ", ".

But now that we have changed how the name is displayed, we've got to change also the way we save them:

```py
def edit():
    roaster_raw = roster_text.get(1.0, 'end-1c').split('\n')
    roaster_get = []
    for line in roaster_raw:
        line = line.split(", ")[:-1] # The [:-1] is used for removing the last "."
        roaster_get.append(line)
    with open("player_roster_test.json", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fout:
        fout.write(json.dumps(roaster_get))
```

I hope this will work for you :)